# Can't decode URL to correct value

Tags: c#, urlencode, urldecode

The following code:

```
context.Response.Write(
    context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
    + "\n" + Uri.UnescapeDataString(context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
    + "\n" + context.Server.UrlDecode(context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
    + "\n" + HttpUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
);
```

Outputs:

```
/uploads/324/d7925fa2-2d3a-4cae-ba3d-e22f48cbe55c/c/1415663111_250/regenera%20hp%20-%20c%C3%B3pia%20(2).png
/uploads/324/d7925fa2-2d3a-4cae-ba3d-e22f48cbe55c/c/1415663111_250/regenera hp - cÃ³pia (2).png
/uploads/324/d7925fa2-2d3a-4cae-ba3d-e22f48cbe55c/c/1415663111_250/regenera hp - cÃ³pia (2).png
/uploads/324/d7925fa2-2d3a-4cae-ba3d-e22f48cbe55c/c/1415663111_250/regenera hp - cÃ³pia (2).png
```

Using a tool like [this one](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) and inputting `/uploads/324/d7925fa2-2d3a-4cae-ba3d-e22f48cbe55c/c/1415663111_250/regenera%20hp%20-%20c%C3%B3pia%20(2).png` and pressing decode results in:

`/uploads/324/d7925fa2-2d3a-4cae-ba3d-e22f48cbe55c/c/1415663111_250/regenera hp - cópia (2).png`

Why are my attempts at URL decoding not resulting in the correct value?

Comment: `HttpUtility.UrlDecode("...regenera%20hp%20-%20c%C3%B3pia%20(2).png")` seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: @mm8 for me that code returns `...regenera hp - cÃ³pia (2).png` not `...regenera hp - cópia (2).png`

Comment: @mm8 actually it works on pages, but not in my IHttpModule

Answer (score 1):

[`HttpUtility.Decode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpUtility_UrlDecode_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_) has an overload that allows you to specify the encoding; you'll need to match the encoding the URL was originally encoded in using that overload.

In your case, it looks like you'll want UTF8:-

`var decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url, Encoding.UTF8);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
```

[image]

Comment: Results in same values as other methods

Comment: Maybe is something with your local configuration. I don't think is about the code.